# SQL/Rails - NOT IN with nested DISTINCT sql query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have the following method:

```
def school_standards
  @standards = @school.achievement_standards
  .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN term_standards ON achievement_standards.id = term_standards.achievement_standard_id")
  .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN terms ON terms.id = term_standards.term_id")
end
```

And I would like to chain it with something like this to return the records that I want:

```
select achievement_standards.*
where achievement_standard_id not in (select distinct achievement_standard_id where term_year_id = 301)
```

I'm having trouble with the syntax on how to nest a DISTINCT query with a NOT IN...

Comment: You can add `school_standard.where.not(standard_id: Standard.where(term_year_id: 301).select(:standard_id).distinct))`

Comment: `AchievementStandard.where(term_year_id: 301)` is giving me an error that says `column achievement_standards.term_year_id does not exist`. Is it because of how I joined the tables?

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing the FROM in your SQL query?

```
SELECT achievement_standards.*
FROM achievement_standards
WHERE standard_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT standard_id FROM standards WHERE term_year_id = 301)
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to put this into my rails/activerecord query. How should I put this into my method?